# How to detect the current directory in which I run my shell script?

Tags: shell

How may I detect the name of the directory (or better yet the entire path) in which my shell script is run?

Comment: For Bash, see: [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/55075).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

what shell?  What operating system?

For starters try

```
man pwd
$PWD
```

Comment: And if you do want just the directory's name, instead of the full path, read man basename too.

Answer (score 17):

This, I believe, is the most portable way:

```
dir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not as trivial as it looks like. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/in-the-bash-script-how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name)

Comment: The question is about determining the script execution directory, but your answer is for determining the name / directory of the script file.

Comment: @Mat indeed! Must have misunderstood back then. Deleting.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more information? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

alternative method

```
pid=$$
path=$(ps -eo pid,args| awk -vp=$pid '$1~p{print $3}')
case "$path" in
    ./* ) pwd;;
    * ) echo $path;;
esac
```