# How can I set the current working directory to the directory of the script in Bash?

Tags: bash, path, scripting

I'm writing a Bash script. I need the current working directory to always be the directory that the script is located in.

The default behavior is that the current working directory in the script is that of the shell from which I run it, but I do not want this behavior.

Comment: Have you considered putting a wrapper script somewhere like /usr/bin to cd into the (hardcoded) proper directory and then execute your script?

Comment: Why do you need the directory of the script? There's probably a better way to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the behavior you call "obviously undesirable" is in fact entirely necessary -- if I run `myscript path/to/file` I expect the script to evaluate path/to/file relative to MY current directory, not whatever directory the script happens to be located in.  Also, what would you have happen for a script run with `ssh remotehost bash < ./myscript` as the BASH FAQ mentions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: `cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" || exit`

Answer (score 962, accepted):

### TL;DR

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

### The long winded explanation

How does this work and how does it deal with edge and corner cases?

You type a command launching the script in your interactive shell. That interactive shell calls `bash` with some name which tells `bash` the script to run. That `bash` then calls `dirname` with the bash argument which points to the script. Finally, that `bash` then calls `cd` with the output of `dirname` as its argument.

| script invocation command | `bash` argument | `dirname` argument | `cd` argument |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `foo` (found in `$PATH` at `/path/to/foo`) | `/path/to/foo` | `/path/to/foo` | `/path/to` |
| `bash foo` | `foo` | `foo` | `.` |
| `/foo` | `/foo` | `/foo` | `/` |
| `./foo` | `./foo` | `./foo` | `.` |
| `"/pa th/to/foo"` | `/pa th/to/foo` | `/pa th/to/foo` | `/pa th/to` |
| `"./pa th/to/foo"` | `./pa th/to/foo` | `./pa th/to/foo` | `./pa th/to` |
| `"../pa th/to/foo"` | `../pa th/to/foo` | `../pa th/to/foo` | `../pa th/to` |
| `"../../pa th/to/foo"` | `../../pa th/to/foo` | `../../pa th/to/foo` | `../../pa th/to` |
| `"pa th/to/foo"` | `pa th/to/foo` | `pa th/to/foo` | `pa th/to` |
| `--help/foo` | `--help/foo` * | N/A | N/A |
| `--help` | N/A ** | N/A | N/A |

### On symlinks

The `cd` command will follow symlinks if they are involved. A symlink usually exists to be followed, so in most situations following the symlink is the correct thing to do. Why would it be a problem for the code in the script to follow a symlink when it was just fine to follow that same symlink a few microseconds ago when loading the script?

#### On command arguments starting with hyphens

* There is only one case where the argument to the `dirname` could begin with a `-`, and that is the relative path case `--help/foo`. If the script is in a subdirectory called `--help`, the script execution will run `bash --help/foo`, and bash does not know that option `--help/foo` and will therefore abort with an error message. The script will never execute, so it does not matter what the `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` would have executed.

** Note that calling the script `--help` makes the shell not find the command when you are typing `--help` in the same directory. Alternatively, with `$PATH` containing the current directory, the script will be run as `/path/to/--help` or `./--help`, always with something in front of the `-` character.

Unless bash introduces command line arguments with a parameter separated by a `=`, it is unlikely that you could pass a `-` argument to bash which contains a `/` later, and which is accepted by bash.

If you can rely on `dirname` accepting `--` argument (bash builtin `cd` will certainly accept `--`), you can change the script snippet to

```bash
cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"
```

Please do comment if you can figure out a way to construct an argument beginning with `-` which can be sneaked past bash.

#### Nota bene

The above snippet also works with non-bash `/bin/sh`.

Comment: dirname returns '.' when using bash under Windows. So, Paul's answer is better.

Comment: Also returns '.' in Mac OSX

Comment: It's worth noting that things can break if a symbolic link makes up part of `$0`. In your script you may expect, for example, `../../` to refer to the directory two levels above the script's location, but this isn't necessarily the case if symbolic links are in play.

Comment: Returns '.' on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: If you called the script as `./script`, `.` is the correct directory, and changing to `.` it will also end up in the very directory where `script` is located, i.e. in the current working directory.

Comment: Perhaps `cd "$(dirname -- "$0")"` is somewhat better in handling situation where `$0` starts with a minus sign.

Comment: as a note, i would consider using `pushd` / `popd` instead of `cd`. if your script is being executed from the terminal like normal it doesn't matter if you change the pwd because it runs as a child process, but there's always the off-chance that someone is `source`ing the script, or possibly some other tool will execute it in the same process.

Comment: If you run the script from the current directory like so `bash script.sh`, then the value of `$0` is `script.sh`. The only way the `cd` command will "work" for you is because you don't care about failed commands. If you were to use `set -o errexit` (aka: `set -e`) to ensure that your script doesn't blow past failed commands, this would NOT work because `cd script.sh` is an error. The reliable [bash specific] way is `cd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"`

Comment: @BrunoBronosky: `dirname script.sh` prints `.` and exits with exit code 0. Therefore `cd .` is executed, also exiting with exit code 0. I cannot fathom where a failing command would appear.

Comment: Not sure what the first two comments (by Tvaroh and Ben Clayton) are trying to say, but as far as I can see, it's fine that dirname returns '.'. This works fine in Mac OS X for all cases, and Paul's answer (which also returns '.' when it works) doesn't work for 'bash script.sh' in the current directory.

Comment: @dimpiax: Using backticks instead of proper quoting fails for directories whose name contains spaces. I reverted your edit adding a backtick based alternative.

Comment: The quotation marks seem messed up. Shouldn't you escape the inner ones? `cd "$(dirname \"$0\")"`

Comment: @lyuboslav The quotation marks are fine. They are not passed to some subshell as a string to be parsed by that subshell. Those inner quotes are used by the outer shell to run the `dirname` command with a single parameter without interpreting the value of `$0` in any way. Then the outer quotes make sure the output of `dirname` is used as a single parameter to `cd` without interpreting the string in any way.

Comment: Just thought it might be worth mentioning, you can use "pushd" instead of cd, which then allows you to "popd" after the script completes to return to where they launched the script.

Comment: @Aerophilic: A script is run as a separate process, and the current working directory of one process does not affect the current working directory of any other process at all.

Comment: @lyuboslavkanev, ...perhaps you were thinking of backtick-based command substitution syntax, where escaping inner quotes is needed; that's not the case for `$(...)`.

Comment: Declare dirname = $(pwd) to route to current directory

Comment: @SanketPandya That makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Aerophilic If you're doing only one `cd`, you can return by doing `cd -` after the script completes.

Answer (score 395):

The following also works:

```
cd "${0%/*}"
```

The syntax is thoroughly described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393551/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-in-a-bash-script) StackOverflow answer.

Comment: When using bash on Windows use ${0%[\\/]*}

Comment: Sounds interesting, but it doesn't work from the current directory (name of the script is passed instead).

Comment: Explanation how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393551/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Don't forget to enclose in quotes if the path contains whitespace. i.e. cd "${0%/*}"

Comment: How do you deal with a directory that has spaces in it??! The above code works if the directory is clean but if it has space it fails.

Comment: @nus IMHO unreadable is ok for very short strings like this that are always going to be copy-pasted, and don't really need to be understood .

Comment: This fails if the script is called with `bash script.sh` -- `$0` will just be the name of the file

Comment: neither it works if a script is in the root directory, because "${0%/*}" would expand to empty string

Comment: In zsh, this starts a new shell.

Comment: I would say this answer is too succinct. You hardly learn anything about the syntax. Some description about how to read this would be helpful.

Comment: This trick does not spawn a subshell too so is good for speed freaks.

Comment: This returns `/bin` when run from WSL 2 on Windows.

Answer (score 256):

Try the following simple one-liners:

---

#### For all UNIX/OSX/Linux

```
dir="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)"
```

#### Bash

```
dir="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd -P)"
```

<sup>Note: A double dash (--) is used in commands to signify the end of command options, so files containing dashes or other special characters won't break the command.</sup>

<sup>Note: In Bash, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` in favor of `$0`, otherwise the path can break when sourcing it (`source`/`.`).</sup>

---

**For Linux, Mac and other *BSD:**

```
cd "$(dirname "$(realpath -- "$0")")";
```

<sup>Note: `realpath` should be installed in the most popular Linux distribution by default  (like Ubuntu), but in some it can be missing, so you have to install it.</sup>

<sup>Note: If you're using Bash, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` in favor of `$0`, otherwise the path can break when sourcing it (`source`/`.`).</sup>

Otherwise you could try something like that (it will use the first existing tool):

```
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f -- "$0" || realpath -- "$0")")"
```

---

**For Linux specific:**

```
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")"
```

---

**Using GNU readlink on *BSD/Mac:**

```
cd "$(dirname "$(greadlink -f -- "$0")")"
```

Note: You need to have `coreutils` installed
(e.g. 1. Install [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), 2. `brew install coreutils`).

---

**In bash**

In bash you can use [Parameter Expansions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations) to achieve that, like:

```
cd "${0%/*}"
```

but it doesn't work if the script is run from the same directory.

Alternatively you can define the following function in bash:

```
realpath () {
  [[ "$1" = /* ]] && echo "$1" || echo "$PWD/${1#./}"
}
```

<sup>This function takes 1 argument. If argument has already absolute path, print it as it is, otherwise print `$PWD` variable + filename argument (without `./` prefix).</sup>

or here is the version taken from Debian `.bashrc` file:

```
function realpath()
{
    f=$@
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        base=""
        dir="$f"
    else
        base="/$(basename -- "$f")"
        dir="$(dirname -- "$f")"
    fi
    dir="$(cd -- "$dir" && /bin/pwd)"
    echo "$dir$base"
}
```

---

Related:

- [How to detect the current directory in which I run my shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817529/how-to-detect-the-current-directory-in-which-i-run-my-shell-script)
- [How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)
- [Bash script absolute path with OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572030/bash-script-absolute-path-with-osx)
- [Reliable way for a Bash script to get the full path to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself/20265654#20265654)

See also:

[How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)

Comment: a much better answer than the popular ones because it resolves syslinks, and accounts for different OS's. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The top one worked on my Mac... but what does the -- switch do in the `cp` command, @kenorb?

Comment: A double dash (`--`) is used in commands to signify the end of command options, so files containing dashes or other special characters won't break the command. Try e.g. create the file via `touch "-test"` and `touch -- -test`, then remove the file via `rm "-test"` and `rm -- -test`, and see the difference.

Comment: I'd remove my upvote if I could: realpath is deprecated http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136494/whats-the-difference-between-realpath-and-readlink-f

Comment: @lsh It says that only Debian `realpath` package is deprecated, not GNU `realpath`. If you think it's not clear, you can suggest an edit.

Comment: `realpath` is not available in Mac OS Catalina

Comment: Shouldn't all the examples like `cd "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"` also use `--` before the parameter, like `cd "$(dirname -- "$(realpath -- "$0")")"`?

Comment: Just to be clear : the first line doesn't actually answer the question. It seems to only define `$dir`. You'd have to use `cd $dir` afterwards, right?

Comment: @EricDuminil If you only want to cd to the script's directory, `cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"` suffices. If you want to use that path elsewhere, then you have to include the `pwd -P` part so that you get an absolute path without symlinks.

Comment: @FWDekker: What I meant is that `dir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)` doesn't set the current working directory to the directory of the script (the original question). It simply defines a variable, without changing the working directory.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, I also found that a bit confusing in the answer. The actual answer to the question would be to execute the first line and then do `cd "$dir"` afterwards (the `""` are important in case the path contains whitespace), as you suggested. Alternatively, you can only execute `cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"`, which is much shorter and achieves the same thing, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @FWDekker: I typically don't use whitespace in file names, but it's still a good habit to use double quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 98):

```
cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
```

It's easy. It works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works on OSX and Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: This works great when the script B is sourced from other script A and you need to use paths relative to script B. Thank you.

Comment: This also works in **Cygwin** for those of us unfortunate enough to have to touch Windows.

Comment: Or `cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" || exit`

Comment: Works on macOS Mojave

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer works well for scripts that have not been symlinked elsewhere, such as into `$PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

However if the script is run via a symlink,

```
ln -sv ~/project/script.sh ~/bin/; 
~/bin/script.sh
```

This will cd into the `~/bin/` directory and not the `~/project/` directory, which will probably break your script if the purpose of the `cd` is to include dependencies relative to `~/project/`

The symlink safe answer is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")"  # cd current directory
```

`readlink -f` is required to resolve the absolute path of the potentially symlinked file.

The quotes are required to support filepaths that could potentially contain whitespace (bad practice, but its not safe to assume this won't be the case)

Answer (score 16):

There are a lot of *correct* answers in here, but one that tends to be more useful for me (making sure a script's relative paths remain predictable/work) is to use pushd/popd:

```
pushd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE:0})"
trap popd EXIT

# ./xyz, etc...
```

This will push the source file's directory on to a navigation stack, thereby changing the working directory, but then, when the script exits (for whatever reason, including failure), the `trap` will run `popd`, restoring the current working directory before it was executed. If the script were to `cd` and then fail, your terminal could be left in an unpredictable state after the execution ends - the trap prevents this.

Answer (score 11):

This script seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=`realpath $0`
cd `dirname $mypath`
pwd
```

The pwd command line echoes the location of the script as the current working directory no matter where I run it from.

Comment: `realpath` is unlikely to be installed everywhere. Which may not matter, depending on the OP's situation.

Comment: My system doesn't have `realpath` but it does have `readlink` which seems to be similar.

Comment: Which dist doesn't have realpath installed by default? Ubuntu has it.

Answer (score 3):

I take this and it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
CUR_DIR=$(pwd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the real path to your script

```
if [ -L $0 ] ; then
    ME=$(readlink $0)
else
    ME=$0
fi
DIR=$(dirname $ME)
```

(This is answer to the same my question here: [Get the name of the directory where a script is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373132/get-name-of-directory-wher-script-is-executed))

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "`dirname $(readlink -f ${0})`"
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: ${0}                   would give the file name of the script. 
readlink -f {0}     would give that script's absolute path.
dirname            would extract the script located path from previous result.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers either don't handle files which are symlinked via a relative path, aren't one-liners or don't handle BSD (Mac).  A solution which does all three is:

```
HERE=$(cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"; cd -P "$(dirname "$(readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" || echo .)")"; pwd)
```

First, cd to bash's conception of the script's directory.  Then readlink the file to see if it is a symlink (relative or otherwise), and if so, cd to that directory.  If not, cd to the current directory (necessary to keep things a one-liner).  Then echo the current directory via `pwd`.

You could add `--` to the arguments of cd and readlink to avoid issues of directories named like options, but I don't bother for most purposes.

You can see the full explanation with illustrations here:

https://www.binaryphile.com/bash/2020/01/12/determining-the-location-of-your-script-in-bash.html

Answer (score -9):

```
echo $PWD
```

PWD is an environment variable.

Comment: This only gives the directory called from, not the directory where the script is.

Answer (score -11):

If you just need to print present working directory then you can follow this.

```
$ vim test

#!/bin/bash
pwd
:wq to save the test file.
```

Give execute permission:

```
chmod u+x test
```

Then execute the script by `./test` then you can see the present working directory.

Comment: The question was how to ensure the script runs in its _own_ directory, including if that is _not_ the working directory. So this is not an answer. Anyway, why do this instead of just... running `pwd`? Seems like a lot of wasted keypresses to me.