# What is the meaning of ${0%/*} in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to understand a test script, which includes the following segment:

```
SCRIPT_PATH=${0%/*}
if [ "$0" != "$SCRIPT_PATH" ] && [ "$SCRIPT_PATH" != "" ]; then 
    cd $SCRIPT_PATH
fi
```

What does the `${0%/*}`  stand for? Thanks

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It is called [`Parameter Expansion`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations). Take a look at [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations) and the rest of the site.

What `${0%/*}` does is, it expands the value contained within the *argument 0* (which is the path that called the script) after removing the string `/*` suffix from the end of it.

So, `$0` is the same as `${0}` which is like any other argument, eg. `$1` which you can write as `${1}`. As I said `$0` is special, as it's not a *real* argument, it's always there and represents name of script. Parameter Expansion works within the `{` `}` -- curly braces, and `%` is one type of Parameter Expansion.

`%/*` matches the last occurrence of `/` and removes anything (`*` means anything) after that character. Take a look at this simple example:

```
$ var="foo/bar/baz"
$ echo "$var"
foo/bar/baz
$ echo "${var}"
foo/bar/baz
$ echo "${var%/*}"
foo/bar
```

Comment: so, it's aa the `dirname($0)`

Comment: in this script, yes, it works like `dirname "$0"` but it could cause problems. If you called the script like this: `bash script` then `${0/*}` doesn't give you the path, it returns the scriptname, or if you specified full path (_/path/to/script_) it returns nothing, so it's not guaranteed to work as expected in all situations.

Comment: I was busy typing a question on superuser about a line that has this, I wrote in my question that I'd usually type parts of the code into google to get a result but seemingly I forgot that but as soon as I broke up my question and analysed it before posting, I googled just `${0%}` and landed here, you have made it clear for me :)

Comment: See also "Get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself

Comment: `echo ${var%%/*}` --> 
`foo`