# Call one shell script from another script using relative paths

Tags: csh

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "This is the main programme"
./printsth
```

I want to call the script `printsth` from within this script using relative paths. Is there a way to do so? By relative paths I mean path relative to where my calling script is.

Comment: why do you think this isn't working? Learn to turn on your shell debugging, ie `set -vx` (or similar for csh) AND `echo $cwd` etc to see where you are at. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

You can refer to the current working directory with `$cwd`.  So if you want to call `printsth` with a path relative to the current working directory, start the line with `$cwd`.

For example, if you want to call the `printsth` in the current directory, say:

```
$cwd/printsth
```

If you want to call the `printsth` one directory above:

```
$cwd/../printsth
```

Be sure it's a `csh` script though (ie. the first line is `#!/bin/csh`).  If it's an `sh` or `bash` script, you need to use `$PWD` (for 'present working directory'), not `$cwd`.

EDIT:

If you want a directory relative to the script's directory, not the current working directory, then you can do this:

```
setenv SCRIPTDIR `dirname $0`
$SCRIPTDIR/printsth
```

That will set `$SCRIPTDIR` to the same directory as the original script.  You can then build paths relative to that.

Comment: can you do this without using $cwd and $pwd

Comment: Well, actually, the default for `csh` is to use the current working directory any way, so `./printsth` will look in CWD anyway.  If you want to look in the same directory as the original script, that's actually a little harder.  Which is it you want?

Comment: I want to look in the same directory as orig script

Comment: In MacOS w/ ZSH at least, `setenv` isn't a thing, but you can use `SCRIPTDIR=\`dirname $0\``

Answer (score 3):

Running script as `./printsth` won't work always, as relative path would depend on directory from which the main script has been run.

One solution would be to make sure that we enter the directory where the script is present, then run it:

```
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"
./printsth
```

For more examples, see: [How to set current working directory to the directory of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3349105/55075)

See also: [How to convert absolute path into relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564634/55075)