# Run .command–file in the folder it's located?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command-line

I have a file called execute.command. When I execute it by opening it. It runs from my users folder. I would like it to run in the folder where it is located. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the script to change working directory to script-location directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

More answers here : [Bash script: set current working directory to the directory of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/bash-script-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)

Answer (score 0):

I added cd `dirname $0` to the top of the command line. This will cd you into the correct folder. Here are more details.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041217111834902