# shell does not recognize graddle wrapper

Tags: shell, gradle, gitlab, gradlew

I have shell script as following -

[image]

Since gradlew is on project root, it is invoked as `../gradlew clean` which is one level above the `backend_test.sh` file -

[image]

However Gitlab ci job fails with following error -

`./test-runners/backend_test.sh: line 21: ../gradlew: No such file or directory`

If I move `backend_test.sh` also on root level and update shell file to invoke `gradlew` as `./gradlew clean` then there is no error. What am I doing wrong when `backend_test.sh` is not on root level?

**Update:**

Running shell locally i.e. `./backend_test.sh` gets me following error -

```
Configure project : 
Evaluating root project 'test-runners' using build file 
'/Users/tarunkumar/dev/git/system-test/test-runners/build.gradle'.
All  projects evaluated.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'test-runners'.
```

Why is `build.gradle` looked up in `test-runner` folder even though it is is on same level as `test-runner`?

Comment: Looking at the directory tree I'm not sure why you think that gradlew `is one level above the test-runner folder` - it's in the same folder.

Comment: I believe error is clear, is not able to find `gradlew` on your script's 21st line. May be give it a try to give an absolute path while running it and it should fly then IMHO.

Comment: Wrong wordings @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, gradle wrapper is one level above the shell script. Have updated qs.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 project is not to be run only on my machine and hence absolute path does not help. `../gradlew` is supposed to look at parent folder where gradle wrapper is available.

Comment: @Tarun, ok, so you mean path of this file is not fixed? If yes then we could run a find command in shell get its path and then do your operation with complete path, please do let me know what you think on this one, cheers.

Comment: gradle wrapper path is fixed from project root and hence I used `../gradlew ` to get to root of project, which obviously does not work and I want to know why?.

Comment: @Tarun, please bear with me I am not an expert of your tool/language. but how about `cd .. && ./gradlew  clean.....your command from here` which means go one level above and then run the script, kindly do let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Same error with `cd .. && ./gradlew`

Comment: @Tarun, then let us check what's the current path of your script before running this, do like `cd .. && pwd && ./gradlew` which should print current path too, let me know what it prints.

Comment: This is what I get - `+ cd ..
 + pwd
 + ./gradlew clean backendTestByGroup 
 ./test-runners/backend_test.sh: line 22: ./gradlew: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relative paths are evaluated relatively to the current working directory. If you are using a shell, the working directory is often shown in your shell prompt. There is no link between your working directory and the directory of the currently processed file. This behavior explains all of your problems:

---

> Since `gradlew` is on project root, it is invoked as `../gradlew clean` which is one level above the `backend_test.sh` file -

On CI servers, all processes are usually invoked using the root directory as working directory (I'm not sure about GitLab CI, but I guess that it behaves this way, too). Now `../gradlew` will be evaluated relatively to your root directory, which won't work, since it searches for `gradlew` in the parent directory of whatever GitLab CI uses as a temporary folder. You can check this behavior by locally navigating a shell to your project directory and then invoking `test-runners/backend_test.sh`, it should result in the same error.

> If I move `backend_test.sh` also on root level and update shell file to invoke `gradlew` as `./gradlew clean` then there is no error.

Well, of course this works as long as the script will be invoked from your project directory, which is the default on CI servers, as we already noticed. Locally you can simply navigate to your project directory and just invoke `backend_test.sh`.

> Running shell locally i.e. `./backend_test.sh` gets me following error

Well, now we got the same problem the other way around. Your script can find `../gradlew` and Gradle is invoked, but sadly, Gradle will evaluate the working directory to find the relevant `build.gradle` file. But now the working directory is inside your `test-runners` folder and Gradle will search this folder for a `build.gradle` file. If there is no `build.gradle` file inside that folder, Gradle does not care at all, instead it just assumes there is an empty `build.gradle` file. Now Gradle uses this (empty) project to run the build, but since there is no task `clean` in the (empty) project, Gradle fails.

Comment: Is there no way to keep files in test-runners folder and not have them on root where gradle files are available? I have multiple sh files on test-runners and having them on root level makes project impression bit bloated and not well organized. Thanks for taking time to respond on vacations days.

Comment: You can keep the file inside the `test-runners` folder and change `../gradlew` to `./gradlew` in your script files. This way it should work on CI. Locally you would need to invoke the scripts from the project directory (navigate there and call `test-runners/backend_test.sh`).

Comment: Alternatively you could edit your script files to [automatically change the working directory to the directory of the script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/how-to-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script-in-bash).

Comment: `./gradlew` did the trick. Fun fact: IDEA changed `./gradlew` to `../gradlew` when I moved sh files to `test-runners` folder.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes those automatic refactorings get a little bit out of hand.