# Can't run a python file from shell script in the same directory

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to call a shell script from a Python program which in turn runs a Python program.So i created one file called `run.sh` have following lines of code,

```
source venv/bin/activate
python main.py
```

The above script will be called by this code,

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import subprocess

class Handler:

    ENTRYPOINT = 'run.sh'

    def run(self, project_path):
        if os.path.exists(project_path):
            subprocess.call(['bash', project_path+self.ENTRYPOINT])
        else:
            print('Project path does not exist!')
```

So, whenever the above run method is executed It throws this error

> python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The run.sh file & main.py file resides in the same level. I don't know much about shell scripting & just Googling my way around but I can't find the reason for the above error.Not even sure if it has anything to do with that shell script.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The location of the `run.sh` file is not relevant for your problem. Do in your script a `ls -ld $PWD/*.py` right before the Python call, to see what Python files you have in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are calling `run.sh` from another directory than the directory the script resides on ? If so, this would explain it all. You are using a *relative* path, which is resolved depending on the current working directory (`pwd`).

To make the script work from anywhere, have a look at [How can I set the current working directory to the directory of the script in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/how-can-i-set-the-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script-in-ba).

On linux:

```sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")" # cd into the directoy where the run.sh is
python main.py
```

Comment: Thanks @Derlin. It is working now. The above link helped to understand the issue.