# How a script know his own name in bash?

Tags: bash, path

I launch script.sh and inside it i want to know what is his name

Is there a standard procedure to know the scripts name ? the idea is to be able to extract the name from teh full path + name contained in `$0`

Thanks

Comment: So are you just looking for `basename`?

Comment: Or are you asking about dereferencing symlinks (perhaps with `readlink`)?

Comment: there are many ways to extract the file name from the full path like using basename,cut,awk etc.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name-in-a-bash-script and note that $0 will pull the parent name if you exec the script with source

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `$0` will always contain the name of the script. Use basename to extract the name.

`basename /some/really/long/dir/path/myscripts/coolscript.sh` will print `coolscript.sh`

So in your script, you could do this:

```
my_scriptname="$(basename $0)"
```

Comment: This `my_scriptname=$(basename "$0")` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

```
script="${0##*/}"
```

**Edit:**

This does the same thing as `basename $0`. It strips off the last slash and everything before it from `$0` using Bash's brace expansion.

Answer (score 1):

`basename $0` will give you the script name

Comment: `basename` doesn't strip extensions unless you ask it to.