# $0 in sourced Bash script not returning script name

Tags: macos, bash

When I reference $0 in a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script on my Mac running [Mac OS X v10.6.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard), I get `-bash`, not the name of the script.

I ran the script described in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/in-the-bash-script-how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo '# arguments called with ($@) -->  '"$@"
echo '# $1 -------------------------->  '"$1"
echo '# $2 -------------------------->  '"$2"
echo '# path to me ($0) ------------->  '"$0"
echo '# parent path (${0%/*}) ------->  '"${0%/*}"
echo '# my name (${0##*/}) ---------->  '"${0##*/}"
echo
```

The following is produced:

```
> . show_parms.sh foo

# arguments called with ($@) -->  foo
# $1 -------------------------->  foo
# $2 -------------------------->
# path to me ($0) ------------->  -bash
# parent path (${0%/*}) ------->  -bash
# my name (${0##*/}) ---------->  -bash
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That makes sense since you’re sourcing the script

```
. show_parms.sh foo
```

instead of executing it

```
./show_parms.sh foo
```

As explained in this [answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/in-the-bash-script-how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name/639500#639500), you can use `$BASH_SOURCE` to know the name of the file from which commands are being sourced.

Comment: Okay, I'm a dufus.  $BASH_SOURCE did the trick.  I like that solution as well because it is reliably, giving me what I expected regardless of how the script is invoked.  I obviously didn't try everything suggested in that answer.  Thanks, Bavarious, for your help.

Answer (score 5):

$0 returns the name of the process. By using the . operator, you're just reading the script into your *existing* bash process and evaluating the commands it contains; the name of the process remains "-bash", so that's what you see. You have to actually execute the script as its own process:

```
chmod +x show_parms.sh
./show_params.sh foo
```

And then you'll get what you expect. This isn't OS X specific; this is just how bash (or sh) works.

Comment: Thanks Ernest.  Since I want to get the script name info regardless of how it was invoked, I'll use $BASH_SOURCE as suggested below, which works both ways.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using the . operator.  If you just typed

```
show_parms.sh foo
```

you would get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks ditkin.  $BASH_SOURCE is what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.