# Retrive the file system position where a bash script is saved

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the bash script how do I know the script file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/in-the-bash-script-how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name)

I often need the file system of a bash script to reference other needed resources. Normally use the following code in line after the shebang line. It sets a variable called 'scriptPos' contains the current path of the scripts

```
scriptPos=${0%/*}
```

It works fine, but is there something more intuitive to replace the shell expansion?

Comment: It contains a similar solution like my way. The problem is I forget the syntax every time and only take it with copy and paste from script to script :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is

```
scriptPos=$(dirname $0)
```

which comes at the cost of an extra process, but is more self-descriptive. If the script is in the current directly, the output differs (for the better, in my opinion):

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptPos=$(dirname $0)

echo '$0:' $0
echo 'dirname:' $scriptPos
echo 'expansion:' ${0%/*}

$ bash tmp.bash
$0: tmp.bash
dirname: .
expansion: tmp.bash
```

UPDATE: An attempt to address the shortcomings pointed out by jm666.

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptPos=$( v=$(readlink "$0") && echo $(dirname "$v") || echo $(dirname "$0") )
```

Comment: this will not work 1) with symlinked script. (will show the dirname for the symlink). 2) for the relative path will show "../../dir", not the place of the script in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There's `dirname` but it requires a `fork`:

```
scriptPos=$(dirname "$0")
```

Comment: ... and isn't necessarily more intuitive.

Comment: @user1651840: try `strace -e execve -f` with `dirname` in a script. @tripleee: well I seem to remember this one, while I always have check the parameter expansion.