# How can I get the path to the currently running shell script (cshell linux)

Tags: linux

Linux/CSHELL:

How can I get the path to a tcsh script that is being sourced?
This is not $PWD.  Rather, the path to the script (file).

Versions/specifics:

% echo $SHELL $PLATFORM
/tool/pandora/bin/tcsh linux_3.10.0_64
ls -l /tool/pandora/bin/tcsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pandora pandora 33 Oct 20  2016 /tool/pandora/bin/tcsh -> ../.package/tcsh-6.19.00/bin/tcsh

There are lots of notes in here for this type of thing.  But I didn't see one for linux c-shell.

Thanks in Advance !

Example:

I have a file /home/myid/my_cshell.csh...

```
set a = `readlink -f ${0}`
echo $a
echo ${0}

source /home/myid/my_cshell.csh
/tool/pandora/.package/tcsh-6.19.00/bin/tcsh
/tool/pandora/bin/tcsh
```

This is giving me the path to tcsh, not /home/myid/my_cshell.csh

The script above works fine if I tcsh it, but not source it.
I need the path to the file being sourced.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/192319/2422776 (admittedly it's about bash, but I think it should be applicable to cshell too)

Comment: It's in the `$0` variable. Unlike with the bourne(-again) shell, you can't fake it via `csh -c '...' argv0`: in `csh`, `argv0` will become `$1` instead of `$0`.

Comment: You can't, sourcing doesn't exec a new shell to replace the parent ... what's the purpose of this exercise, though?

Comment: Why are you using c-shell? Is sh/bash/ash, or some more "normal" shell not available (if this is the case, what linux distro is it, so I can make sure to avoid it)? Is this some act of self-flagellation (you have sinned, and C-shell is your punishment) ???

Comment: set the file name in the main script, before sourcing it. You can use an alias for that: `alias sourcex 'set the_file=\!:1; source \!:1'`, then `sourcex /path/to/file` and in `/path/to/file` `ls $the_file:q`.

Comment: @Z4-tier I'm not sure that getting the path of the file being sourced (eg. with `. file`) from inside it is too obvious in sh/bash/ash either.

Comment: @mosvy My question was more philosophical: in 2020, is there *any* reason to script in `csh`??? Seems about as popular as `smalltalk` or `pascal` these days...

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have `readlink` available:

```
readlink -f "${0}"
```

should work. `${0}` will give you the relative path, and `readlink -f` will resolve it to the absolute path.

There must already be some way to reference the file... If not, how could it be sourced in the first place? So I suppose the problem is that `${0}` referecnes the parent's file system location, and not the sourced file.  In that case, `readlink -f <file>` should still work, but maybe try calling it first, and then pass the result when you run `source`. Like this:
main.csh:

```
#!/bin/csh

set p=`readlink -f source.csh`
source source.csh "${p}"
```

source.csh:

```
#!/bin/csh
set pmain=`readlink -f "${0}"`
echo "my path is ${1}. main.csh's path is ${pmain}"
```

Comment: just like in the bourne shell, writing `${var}` instead of `$var` does not add any extra value; you should _quote_ it with `$var:q` (which also works with arrays) if you don't want it to be split and globbed.

Comment: @mosvy https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/6689725. Agreed on quoting though, I corrected that.